# Is using legacy OpengGL (Windows's implementation - 1.1) bad practise?

Tags: opengl, frameworks, cross-platform

I'm currently developing a GameEngine API/framework so far I have an OpenGL 4.6 context where I load all the functions by myself (no OpenGL wrapper). The Engine is still under heavy construction, but some 3D stuff is already possible. Now the Engine was targeted to primarily draw 3D objects, but I'm also considering 2D stuff (though I haven't started yet to implement it).

Right now I'm creating kind of a user interface framework (which can be used instead of the 3D or 2D engine and likewise) "like" MFC, WinForms... you name it. For that, I'm using Windows's OpenGL 1.1 implementation, and that's where we get to my actual question.

Is using such an old OpenGL, or any legacy OpenGL version, considered as a bad practice? I know this question may be opinion-based, but especially in my case, I think it's the easiest way to create reusable controls; besides from that it's super interesting to create controls like a button all by myself, you have to think about everything. And I don't think Microsoft will remove it soon from their API if so, this would mean, we wouldn't be able to get an OpenGL context at all if I'm not completely wrong on that.

**Additional information:**

The way people/I should use the framework is, you would need to choose one of the types, the Engine can provide, such as 3D, 2D or creating a "normal" user-interface.
The reason I choose Windows's OpenGL implementation for the user-interface is, that it would also be possible to create a user-interface for Windows XP.

I currently use functions like `glBegin()`, `glEnd()`, `glVertex2f()` and `glColor3f()` to draw a button and `wglUseFontBitmaps()`, `glPushAttrib()`, `glListBase()`, `glCallLists()`, `glPopAttrib()` to draw the text.

Regarding the OpenGL context, I use Nehe's way to get a context:

http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/creating_an_opengl_window_(win32)/13001/

So for the user-interface, I don't use the 4.6 context but 1.1

Comment: What exactly are you intending to use? There are OpenGL 1.1 functions that are still good (such as `glGet`, `glIsEnabled` etc.) For the functions you want to use, check if they are still in the OpenGL specification and not marked as deprecated. Any such function should be safe to use. For all other functions, it is not guaranteed that they are available with a 4.6 context.

Comment: You must have a good reason for using OGL 1.1. Some of your customers still use a quite old hardware may be a good reason, unlikely though. Using some API for text rendering or alike is not worth enough.

Comment: @Ripi2 not that unlikely/uncommon than you would think. A lot of our customers still using MS-DOS and floppies !!! Not going for more modern HW because they can not due to lack of SW for expensive machinery in CNC world (and will not invest horrible prices for new CNC when the old one is still in working condition). That is not the case for GAMEs but many people using "older" notebooks (especially with IntelHD) where many things GL desktop people take for granted simply do not work as should... Had to revert to GL 1.0/1.1 all the time due that ...

Comment: @ Nico Schertler Well, you can use only one of the mentioned "options" at a time, like 3D, 2D, and the User-Interface. I'll add some more information to clarify what I indent to do/use